# Prettier text dialogs in OS X scripts

Tags: macos, applescript, objective-c, cocoadialog

I'm getting pretty sick of these default AppleScript and [cocoaDialog](http://mstratman.github.com/cocoadialog/#documentation) dialogs:

[image]

I'd like to replace them with something closer to this:

[image]

Has anyone made a shell executable like cocoaDialog with a custom look for windows? Are there any other options for getting less ugly text dialogs in shell scripts or AppleScripts?

Comment: Real AppleScript applications are not an option? Apart from that, I support this question. It's embarrassing.

Comment: +1 for using an [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com/) screenshot as an example :).

Comment: I'd say that's a fine looking dialog compared to `Java SWING/AWT` GUI.

Comment: CocoaDialog has recently come under development again, not that it fixes this, but it's worth mentioning...

Comment: You might want to ask that on SO.

Comment: @sims The question isn't specific to any language, but it is specific to OS X. And I'm mainly looking for existing solutions, not implementing one myself.

Comment: @17510427541297, Then perhaps the applescript and objective-c tags are out of place? Anyway, you may get some more replies over there. It could be dismal though. SO et al has kind of soaked up the masses...

Answer (score 2):

An apparently very popular one is [24U Appearance OSAX](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/7865/24u-appearance-osax).

It will let you add more components to the dialog windows through "Better Dialog Utility" – if that's what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be [official themes](http://www.insanelymac.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=117568&mode=linear) and [3rd-party themers](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?s=a97d5b488ec03e94cf6784ec1b94b5ca&t=93977&page=2).

Comment: If those dialog settings are controlled via the specified scripts, then the documentation linked in the OP doesn't mention them. If i had a Mac, i'd try [Magnifique](http://mac.appstorm.net/how-to/graphics-how-to/an-introduction-to-changing-os-x-themes/). Proper design doesn't re-invent the wheel and thus uses adequate available (system) components.